# Optimizing a Ray Tracer

Tags: c++, optimization, graphics, rendering, raytracing

I'm tasked with optimizing the following ray tracer:

```
void Scene::RayTrace() 
{

    for (int v = 0; v < fb->h; v++)  // all vertical pixels in framebuffer
    {
        calculateFPS(); // calculates the current fps and prints it

        for (int u = 0; u < fb->w; u++) // all horizontal pixels in framebuffer
        {

            fb->Set(u, v, 0xFFAAAAAA); // background color
            fb->SetZ(u, v, FLT_MAX);  // sets the Z values to all be maximum at beginning
            V3 ray = (ppc->c + ppc->a*((float)u + .5f) + ppc->b*((float)v + .5f)).UnitVector(); // gets the camera ray

            for (int tmi = 0; tmi < tmeshesN; tmi++)  // iterates over all triangle meshes
            {
                if (!tmeshes[tmi]->enabled) // doesn't render a tmesh if it's not set to be enabled
                    continue;
                for (int tri = 0; tri < tmeshes[tmi]->trisN; tri++) // iterates over all triangles in the mesh
                {
                    V3 Vs[3]; // triangle vertices
                    Vs[0] = tmeshes[tmi]->verts[tmeshes[tmi]->tris[3 * tri + 0]];
                    Vs[1] = tmeshes[tmi]->verts[tmeshes[tmi]->tris[3 * tri + 1]];
                    Vs[2] = tmeshes[tmi]->verts[tmeshes[tmi]->tris[3 * tri + 2]];
                    V3 bgt = ppc->C.IntersectRayWithTriangleWithThisOrigin(ray, Vs); // I don't entirely understand what this does

                    if (bgt[2] < 0.0f || bgt[0] < 0.0f || bgt[1] < 0.0f || bgt[0] + bgt[1] > 1.0f) 
                        continue;
                    if (fb->zb[(fb->h - 1 - v)*fb->w + u] < bgt[2])
                        continue;

                    fb->SetZ(u, v, bgt[2]);
                    float alpha = 1.0f - bgt[0] - bgt[1];
                    float beta = bgt[0];
                    float gamma = bgt[1];
                    V3 Cs[3]; // triangle vertex colors
                    Cs[0] = tmeshes[tmi]->cols[tmeshes[tmi]->tris[3 * tri + 0]];
                    Cs[1] = tmeshes[tmi]->cols[tmeshes[tmi]->tris[3 * tri + 1]];
                    Cs[2] = tmeshes[tmi]->cols[tmeshes[tmi]->tris[3 * tri + 2]];
                    V3 color = Cs[0] * alpha + Cs[1] * beta + Cs[2] * gamma;
                    fb->Set(u, v, color.GetColor()); // sets this pixel accordingly

                }

            }


        }
        fb->redraw();
        Fl::check();
    }

}
```

Two things:

1. I don't entirely understand what `ppc->C.IntersectRayWithTriangleWithThisOrigin(ray, Vs);` does. Can anyone explain this, in terms of ray-tracing, to me? Here is the function inside my "Planar Pinhole Camera" class (this function was given to me):

   ```
   V3 V3::IntersectRayWithTriangleWithThisOrigin(V3 r, V3 Vs[3]) 
   {

       M33 m; // 3X3 matrix class
       m.SetColumn(0, Vs[1] - Vs[0]);
       m.SetColumn(1, Vs[2] - Vs[0]);
       m.SetColumn(2, r*-1.0f);
       V3 ret; // Vector3 class
       V3 &C = *this;
       ret = m.Inverse() * (C - Vs[0]);
       return ret;

   }
   ```

The basic steps of this are apparent, I just don't see what it's actually *doing*.

2. How would I go about optimizing this ray-tracer from here? I've found something online about "kd trees," but I'm unsure how complex they are. Does anyone have some good resources on simple solutions for optimizing this? I've had some difficulty deciphering what's out there.

Thanks!

Comment: For some reason, I can't get that second function to "code block" correctly. Sorry about that.

Comment: seems like you need two levels of indentation for code blocks inside lists. Otherwise for general formatting help html comments `<!-- -->` always work as breaks. (Useful for separating two code blocks that are directly after each other .

Comment: Probably the best answer you're going to get about that function's purpose is from asking the person who you're optimizing this code for. Personally I wouldn't touch someone else's code with a 10 foot pole if they haven't done any documenting, especially in a program as complex as a ray tracer.

Comment: Problem is that this is our final project for University, and the professor wrote the code. As far as emailing him for assistance...that's usually met with "figure it out."
Although I believe the function may have something to do with calculating the ray from the eye to the current triangle?

Comment: Ah, university. If your professor were to provide this mess in a real world job, his co-workers would murder him on the spot. In any case yes it appears to be ray/triangle collision detection code.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the largest optimisation by far would be to use some sort of [bounding volume hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_volume_hierarchy). Right now the code intersects all rays with all triangles of all objects. With a BVH, we instead ask: "given this ray, which triangles intersect?" This means that for each ray, you generally only need to test for intersection with a handful of primitives and triangles, rather than every single triangle in the scene.

Comment: How complex of a solution would you say that is? As I'm reading it appears to be simply a bounding box around the object. My scene only has a single object, so I assume it'd be fairly easy?

Comment: The difficulty of implementation of such a structure is not related to the complexity of the scene. I'd recommend an [octree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) for ease of implementation, although [k-d trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) tend to perform better if properly implemented.

Comment: I guess I'm a bit confused then.
Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems that BVH essentially puts a 2D bounding box around each object, and then inserts it into an octree (or k-d tree). Wouldn't the octree/k-d tree be unnecessary if there is only a single object?

Comment: The primitives inserted into a BVH are the _triangles_, not the objects. So it is a hierarchical subdivision of the triangles in the scene.

Comment: Hmm. Can you explain that in a little more detail then? It seems that I can only find references to storing the entire objects in the trees, such as this: http://www.3dmuve.com/3dmblog/?p=182

Comment: The idea will always be the same, except that for raytracing we want to subdivide the set of triangles, rather than entire objects. So for an octree, we store a bounding box (or bounding cube) of the entire scene, then divide it into octants recursively, until we have leaf nodes containing the actual triangles. (Note that an octree is not _really_ a bounding volume hierarchy, but rather a binary space partition in three dimensions. The concepts are very similar though.)

Answer (score 0):

1. `IntersectRayWithTriangleWithThisOrigin`

   - from the look of it
   - it creates inverse transform matrix from the triangle edges (triangle basis vectors are X,Y)
   - do not get the Z axis I would expect the ray direction there and not position of pixel (ray origin)
   - but can be misinterpreting something
   - anyway the inverse matrix computation is the biggest problem
   - you are computing it for each triangle per pixel that is a lot
   - faster would be having computed inverse transform matrix of each triangle before raytracing (once)
   - where X,Y are the basis and Z is perpendicular to booth of them facing always the same direction to camera
   - and then just transform your ray into it and check for limits of intersection
   - that is just `matrix*vector` and few `if`s instead of inverse matrix computation
   - another way would be to algebraically solve ray vs. plane intersection
   - that should lead to much simpler equation then matrix inversion
   - after that is that just a mater of basis vector bound checking

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks! What do you mean by "do not get the Z axis I would expect the ray direction there and not position of pixel (ray origin)?" And how exactly would you only do the inverse matrix computation a single time? It requires the different ray as seen in this line above: `V3 ray = (ppc->c + ppc->a*((float)u + .5f) + ppc->b*((float)v + .5f)).UnitVector();`

Comment: @Jestus Now your Z axis is set by the `r*-1.0f` which makes no sense to me (it is most likely result of some algebraic approach) if you use matrix relative to the triangle instead of relative to ray then the matrix will be constant for all rays (Z axis is normal). but you will need to add the result computation because such inverse matrix just transform from world coordinates to triangle. so just compute x,y values of ray for z=0 (all in triangle coordinates) and check if x,y is inside